# How to show particular div using jQuery

Tags: jquery

```js
<div class="companyname" data-companyname="abc" ></div>
<div class="companyname" data-companyname="xyz" ></div>
<div class="companyname" data-companyname="pqr" ></div>
```

I need show only data-companyname="abc" div only....so i used following way in jQuery

```js
$(".companyname").attr('abc').show();
```

How to get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('div[data-companyname="abc"]').show()
```

```css
.companyname {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="companyname" data-companyname="abc">1</div>
<div class="companyname" data-companyname="xyz">2</div>
<div class="companyname" data-companyname="pqr">3</div>
```

use the attr selector

Comment: @SHERINAS glad to help happy coding mate :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **[attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)**

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value exactly equal to a certain value

```
$(".companyname[data-companyname=abc]").show();
```

```js
$(".companyname[data-companyname=abc]").show();
```

```css
.companyname{display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="companyname" data-companyname="abc" >abc</div>
<div class="companyname" data-companyname="xyz" >xyz</div>
<div class="companyname" data-companyname="pqr" >pqr</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :Use attribute selector like below

```
$(".companyname[data-companyname='abc']").show();
```